# Shape inconsistence in my code based on numpy/scipy package

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, shapes, operation

I have 2 matrices and a vector which I multiply by using the `dot()` function of numpy.

```
print D.shape, A.shape, y.shape, type(D), type(A), type(y)
# (236, 236) (236, 236) (236,)
# <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
# <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

y_next = np.dot(D, np.dot(A, y))

print y_next.shape
# (236,)
```

So if the shape of `y_next` is `(236,)` it means it is a 236x1-matrix, correct? Now if I do `print y_next` I get the output below. I just copied the last cupple of rows, but you can see, that the first index (row) is not *unique*. Where does this come from?  I mean a matrix multiplyed by a vector should result in a vector, and a vector can't have the same indices twice by definition. If it has, as the ouput suggests, it would be a matrix.

**Where is my mistake?**

### Output:

```
::  
(230, 212)  0.04
  (230, 205)    0.04
  (230, 187)    0.04
  (230, 11) 0.04
  (231, 230)    0.04
  (231, 212)    0.04
  (231, 205)    0.04
  (231, 187)    0.04
  (231, 11) 0.04
  (232, 235)    0.0625
  (232, 234)    0.0625
  (232, 233)    0.0625
  (232, 160)    0.0625
  (233, 235)    0.0625
  (233, 234)    0.0625
  (233, 232)    0.0625
  (233, 160)    0.0625
  (234, 235)    0.0625
  (234, 233)    0.0625
  (234, 232)    0.0625
  (234, 160)    0.0625
  (235, 234)    0.0625
  (235, 233)    0.0625
  (235, 232)    0.0625
  (235, 160)    0.0625
   (0, 79)  0.0555555555556
  (0, 3)    0.0555555555556
  (0, 2)    0.0555555555556
  (0, 1)    0.0833333333333
  (1, 80)   0.0555555555556
  (1, 3)    0.0555555555556
  (1, 2)    0.0555555555556
  (1, 0)    0.0833333333333
  (2, 81)   0.00966183574879
  (2, 8)    0.00966183574879
  (2, 7)    0.00966183574879
  (2, 6)    0.00966183574879
  (2, 5)    0.00966183574879
  (2, 4)    0.00966183574879
  (2, 3)    0.0338164251208
  (2, 1)    0.00966183574879
  (2, 0)    0.00966183574879
  (3, 82)   0.00966183574879
  (3, 8)    0.00966183574879
  (3, 7)    0.00966183574879
  (3, 6)    0.00966183574879
  (3, 5)    0.00966183574879
  (3, 4)    0.00966183574879
  (3, 2)    0.0338164251208
  (3, 1)    0.00966183574879
  : :
  (230, 212)    0.04
  (230, 205)    0.04
  (230, 187)    0.04
  (230, 11) 0.04
  (231, 230)    0.04
  (231, 212)    0.04
  (231, 205)    0.04
  (231, 187)    0.04
  (231, 11) 0.04
  (232, 235)    0.0625
  (232, 234)    0.0625
  (232, 233)    0.0625
  (232, 160)    0.0625
  (233, 235)    0.0625
  (233, 234)    0.0625
  (233, 232)    0.0625
  (233, 160)    0.0625
  (234, 235)    0.0625
  (234, 233)    0.0625
  (234, 232)    0.0625
  (234, 160)    0.0625
  (235, 234)    0.0625
  (235, 233)    0.0625
  (235, 232)    0.0625
  (235, 160)    0.0625]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your confusion is the use of the numpy `dot` operator with scipy sparse matrices. For numpy and scipy matrices (note matrices, not arrays), the `*` operator computes dot products, like this:

```
In [47]: import scipy.sparse as sp

In [48]: import numpy as np

In [49]: D=sp.csr.csr_matrix(np.diagflat(np.random.random(100)))

In [50]: A=sp.csr.csr_matrix(np.diagflat(np.random.random(100)))

In [51]: y=np.random.random(100)

In [52]: y_next = A*(D*y)

In [53]: print y_next.shape, type(y_next)
(100,) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [54]: print y_next
[ 0.00478446  0.0234117   0.02234696  0.23123913  0.15545059  0.366065
  0.05674736  0.00238582  0.08701694  0.00099934  0.01687756  0.08190578
  0.17570485  0.08015175  0.00301985  0.00491663  0.09450794  0.1141585
  0.02753342  0.0462671   0.02075956  0.21261696  0.82611774  0.09058998
  0.33545702  0.31456356  0.00260624  0.0449429   0.2431993   0.06302444
  0.01901411  0.02553964  0.02442291  0.02169692  0.15085474  0.41331208
  0.09486585  0.01001604  0.48898697  0.03557272  0.22931588  0.0760863
  0.37686888  0.02801424  0.3280943   0.1695001   0.02890001  0.11712331
  0.02996858  0.43608624  0.00905409  0.00655408  0.01618681  0.1417559
  0.0057121   0.0010656   0.02067559  0.05223334  0.14035328  0.0457123
  0.1273495   0.17688214  0.39300249  0.00625762  0.05356745  0.26719959
  0.08349373  0.05969248  0.02332782  0.0218782   0.1716797   0.04823102
  0.03117486  0.00172426  0.08514879  0.09505655  0.17030885  0.00953221
  0.00134071  0.03951708  0.00243708  0.04247436  0.32152315  0.02039932
  0.00436897  0.00097858  0.08876351  0.00824626  0.12004067  0.01060241
  0.11929884  0.01207807  0.10467955  0.02536641  0.602902    0.04115373
  0.00472405  0.05108167  0.28946041  0.19071962]
```

Alternatively, the sparse matrix classes own `dot` method will also work:

```
In [55]: print D.dot(A.dot(y)) - (D*(A*y))

[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Using `numpy.dot` seems to result in what is internally  a sparse matrix with an `ndarray` type. The repeated entries you are seeing are the individual products which get summed down into final dot products, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the internals of `scipy.sparse` work, but here is your problem:

```
In [1]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [2]: A = csr_matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [3]: y = scipy.array([1, 2])

In [4]: print A
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    2
  (1, 0)    3
  (1, 1)    4

In [5]: print y
[1 2]

In [6]: print scipy.dot(A, y)
[  (0, 0)   1
  (0, 1)    2
  (1, 0)    3
  (1, 1)    4
   (0, 0)   2
  (0, 1)    4
  (1, 0)    6
  (1, 1)    8]
```

Why this happens, I have no idea.

Instead, first make sure both operands are the same type:

```
In [7]: print scipy.dot(A, csr_matrix(y).T)
  (0, 0)    5
  (1, 0)    11

In [13]: scipy.dot(A.toarray(), y)
Out[13]: array([ 5, 11])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What does the `.T` in the first line of the second code block do? I can't find it in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix).

Comment: [Matrix transpose.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T) You may also find this page helpful: [NumPy for Matlab Users](http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)